# fast large scale key-value store for a php program

Tags: php, nosql, key-value, key-value-store

I'm working on a full text index system for a project of mine. As one part of the process of indexing pages it splits the data into a very, very large number of very small pieces.

I have gotten the size of the pieces to be as low as a constant 20-30 bytes, and it could be less, it is basically 2 8 byte integers and a float that make up the actual data.

Because of the scale I'm looking for and the number of pieces this creates I'm looking for an alternative to mysql which has shown significant issues at value sets well below my goal.

My current thinking is that a key-value store would be the best option for this and I have adjusted my code accordingly.

I have tried a number but for some reason they all seem to scale even less than mysql.

I'm looking to store on the order of hundreds of millions or billions or more key-value pairs so I need something that won't have a large performance degradation with size.

I have tried memcachedb, membase, and mongo and while they were all easy enough to set up, none of them scaled that well for me.

membase had the most issues due to the number of keys required and the limited memory available.  Write speed is very important here as this is a very close to even workload, I write a thing once, then read it back a few times and store it for eventual update.

I don't need much performance on deletes and I would prefer something that can cluster well as I'm hoping to eventually have this able to scale across machines but it needs to work on a single machine for now.

I'm also hoping to make this project easy to deploy so an easy setup would be much better.  The project is written in php so it needs to be easy accessed from php.

I don't need to have rows or other higher level abstractions, they are mostly useless in this case and I have already made the code from some of my other tests to get down to a key-value store and that seems to likely be the fastest as I only have 2 things that would be retrieved from a row keyed off a third so there is little additional work done to use a key-value store.  Does anyone know any easy to use projects that can scale like this?

I am using this store to store individual sets of three numbers, (the sizes are based on how they were stored in mysql, that may not be true in other storage locations) 2 eight byte integers, one for the ID of the document and one for the ID of the word and a float representation of the proportion of the document that that word was (number of times the work appeared divided by the number of words in the document).  The index for this data is the word id and the range the document id falls into, every time I need to retrieve this data it will be all of the results for a given word id.  I currently turn the word id, the range, and a counter for that word/range combo each into binary representations of the numbers and concatenate them to form the key along with a 2 digit number to say what value for that key I am storing, the document id or the float value.

Performance measurement was somewhat subjective looking at the output from the processes putting data into or pulling data out of the storage and seeing how fast it was processing documents as well as rapidly refreshing my statistics counters that track more accurate statistics of how fast the system is working and looking at the differences when I was using each storage method.

Comment: Have you tried SimpleDB on amazon? http://aws.amazon.com/simpledb/

Comment: Please add some exemplary data to your question. What is the key? What is the value?

Comment: How can memcachedb be slower than MySQL? How did you measure the performance? Do you require concurrency or not? How did you conduct your tests? Did you test on a single machine? How's your PHP program accessing these values? You need to provide more information, such as how many writes per second you require at minimum.

Comment: I've not tried simple DB but the 10GB limit could easily cause issues with this large of a data set, not to mention this is being done on a colocated server and I'd rather keep the cost to that, not adding to much cost.  I've seen this data set grow well beyond 10GB easily before.

Comment: I don't have specific minimums but I can give a good estimate, I need at least 2-3k reads and 2-3k writes per second on a single machine, and on a cluster probably at least 5-10k of each per second.  I do require concurrency but I don't need instant consistency, but fairly quick consistency, say within 1-5 minutes.

Answer (score 5):

You would need to provide some more data about what you really want to do...

depending on how you define *fast large scale* you have several options:

- [memcache](http://memcached.org/)
- [redis](http://redis.io/)
- [voldemort](http://project-voldemort.com/)
- [riak](http://wiki.basho.com/)

and sooo on.. the list gets pretty big..

**Edit 1:**

Per this post comments I would say that you take a look to cassandra or voldemort. Cassandra isn't a simple KV storage `per se` since you can storage much more complex objects than just `K -> V`

if you care to check cassandra with PHP, take a look to [phpcassa](https://github.com/thobbs/phpcassa). but [redis](http://memcached.org/) is also a good option if you set a replica.

Comment: redis will go onto my list to look into as will voldemort but I'm afraid you either misunderstand my needs or what memcache is, memcache is a temporary memory cache, I'm looking for persistent storage that is much larger than could be stored in my RAM, several of the things I looked into were memcache based but memcache itself isn't really an option.  How will redis perform with this sort of amount of content if it has only a very small amount of RAM, will it work with most of the data only on disk?

Comment: Use memcache for temporary storage and asynchronous queue to distribute tasks for writing to disk. Disk is going to be your I/O bottleneck and every single piece of software out there, no matter how good, can only be as fast as your weakest link - the hard drive. Store in memory initially and write to disk later.

Comment: you *said* KV storage and that is what I answered. you may look to cassandra then. Nothing and I mean nothing that works only with disk will be fast enough. you need a solution that is : ram + disk. but with the information you provided is hard to advice correctly.

Comment: Am I misunderstanding KV storage, my understanding of that was simply that it linked one key to one value without higher level abstractions.  I didn't think KV storage implied anything about what storage backed it.  I am new to this method of data storage though so I might not fully understand it.

Comment: I'll look into cassandra, how easy is it to use it from php?

Answer (score 2):

Here's add a few products and ideas that weren't mentioned above:

- [OrientDB](http://www.orientechnologies.com/orient-db.htm) - this is a graph/document database, but you can use it to store very small "documents" - it is extremely fast, highly scalable, and optimized to handle vast amounts of records.
- [Berkeley DB](http://schlueters.de/blog/archives/134-Berkeley-DB-5-and-PHP.html) - Berkeley DB is a key-value store used at the heart of a number of graph and document databases - supposedly has a SQLite-compatible API that works with PHP.
- [shmop](http://php.net/manual/en/book.shmop.php) - Shared memory operations might be one possible approach, if you're willing to do some dirty-work. If you records are small and have a fixed size, this might work for you - using a fixed record-size and padding with zeroes.
- [handlersocket](http://code.google.com/p/php-handlersocket/) - this has been in development for a long time, and I don't know how reliable it is. It basically lets you use MySQL at a "lower level", almost like a key/value-store. Because you're bypassing the query parser etc. it's much faster than MySQL in general.

If you have a fixed record-size, few writes and lots of reads, you may even consider reading/writing to/from a flat file. Likely nowhere near as fast as reading/writing to shared memory, but it may be worth considering. I suggest you weigh all the pros/cons specifically for your project's requirements, not only for products, but for any approach you can think of. Your requirements aren't exactly "mainstream", and the solution may not be as obvious as picking the right product.